# DreamFactory install database name

Tags: dreamfactory

DreamFactory installer (via php artisan) is prompting "Enter your database name:", not sure what database means, it wants me to set a brand new database name or a name for existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a database for DreamFactory to use to store its configuration options and users. This can be sqlite, mysql, postgres, or sql server (paid option.)
When you run the setup command you need to provide the database connection information for an existing database. If you don't have a database, you can choose the sqlite option instead of one of the others. sqlite is file based and requires no server infrastructure. The database will be created for you automatically in that case.